# How to find the solid angle covered by off-axis rectangle

Tags: geometry

I am looking for the solid angle covered by a rectangle or in this case a single square pixel that is off-axis from a source p. The formulas I have uncovered seem to be good only for the case where the source is in line of sight of the rectangle. Can anyone help? I've included a drawing to help illustrate the problem.
[Rectangle showing normal n in a left handed coordinate system with source p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zz07Y.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The formula for finding the solid angle subtended by a $3D$ surface $S$ at a point $\mathbf{P}$ is

$\Omega = \displaystyle \iint_S \dfrac{\mathbf{P} - \mathbf{r} }{\|\mathbf{P} - \mathbf{r} \|} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} dS $

In the case of a rectangular surface, there is a direct way that does not require any numerical integration, and that is by segmenting the rectangle into two triangles, and finding the solid angle subtended by each triangle at $\mathbf{P}$.  This can be done by finding the angles between the lateral planes of the tetrahedron whose apex is point $\mathbf{P} $ and whose base is the triangle, then one apply the following formula

$ \Omega =  A + B + C - \pi $

where $A,B,C$ are the angles between the lateral planes of the tetrahedron.

Comment: This looks correct, but I'm not allowed to up vote yet.

Comment: That's Okay.  Glad I could help.